# Extract All Triangles in Igraph with Labels

Tags: r, igraph, triangle-count

I have created an igraph with 1000 edges. My goal is to extract all the triangles found in that igraph but to include the label rather than just then number. I also want it to be in a dataframe form that has 3 columns (one for each node of the triangle)

I have tried simply calling:

```
triangles(graph)
```

and that gives a list back with the names all in one column:

```
+ 28431/204 vertices, named:
    [1] node_a                                                
    [2] node_b                   
    [3] node_c 
    [4] node_a                                                
    [5] node_b                   
    [6] node_d                 
    [7] node_a                                                
    [8] node_b                   
    [9] node_e                              
   [10] node_a                                                
+ ... omitted several vertices
```

When I try:

```
adjacent.triangles(graph)
```

it returns all the numbers but not the names of the nodes:

```
[1]  15 103  45 121 152  78 325 325   3  35  90   0 488 283   3   0 325 325 325 325  78  21 190   3
[25] 133   0  47 167 167   6   3 325 505 415   0  36  78 325  78  78  90   6 206   6  36   0  78  49
```

I need to find a function through igraph that can give me the triangles in the following format:

```
COL1         COL2        COL3
node_a       node_b      node_c
node_a       node_b      node_d
node_a       node_b      node_e
node_f       node_g      node_h
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the clique function (assuming g is your graph),

```
cl.tri=cliques(g,min=3,max=3)
```

to find the cliques of size three (triangles) and then assemble them into a dataframe by,

```
df<-lapply(cl.tri,function(x){V(g)$name[x]})

df2=data.frame(matrix(unlist(df),ncol=3,byrow=T))
```

Comment: Thank you. So would I just do an index match to see what the labels are?

Comment: Yes, you could do something like,
    lapply(cl.tri,function(x){V(g)$names[x]})  
before you create the data frame or,
   apply(df, 2, function(x){V(g)$names[x]})
after.  There may be a way to get the cliques function to directly return labels but I'm not sure.

Comment: This was a great start, thanks. When I tried this though an Error came up when I ran the df=data.frame(matrix(unlist(cl.tri),ncol=3,byrow=T)) I tried the first function

Comment: Hey Nick, can you edit your question to include a full working example?  Otherwise I will just have to infer what the issue is.  My response above should use V(g)$name[x]  instead of V(g)$names[x].  It depends how you stored the names of your nodes but I think the igraph default is in the vertex attribute "name".

Comment: That was the error! Thanks Ryan. If you want, you can put an answer down to the question I posted to receive a correct answer, or I can just delete the question....up to you

Comment: I think it's best to delete the other question to avoid confusion.  Glad it worked out for you.